# I need help re-writing a SQL query into LINQ format

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm not good with LINQ yet and could use some help with the syntax.

Thanks!

The below query needs to be written in LINQ for C#.

```
SELECT Galleries.GalleryTitle, Media.*
FROM Galleries 
INNER JOIN Media ON Galleries.GalleryID = Media.GalleryID
WHERE (Galleries.GalleryID = 150)
ORDER BY MediaDate DESC, MediaID DESC
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or with query syntax:

```
var query = from g in db.Galleries
            join m in db.Media on g.GalleryID equals m.GalleryID
            where g.GalleryID == 150
            orderby m.MediaDate descending, m.MediaID descending
            select new { g.GalleryTitle, Media = m };
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var query = db.Galleries
            .Join(db.Media, g => g.GalleryID, m => m.GalleryID, (g, m) => new {g, m})
            .Where(r.g.GalleryID == 150)
            .Select(res => new {res.g.GalleryTitle, Media = res.m}
            .OrderByDescending(o => o.Media.MediaDate)
            .ThenByDescending(o => o.Media.MediaID);
```